# Subtract one DateTime from another and return days

Tags: php, datetime, date

I have 2 DateTime objects. One which represents 2 days from now and the other which represents 2 days and 6 months from now.

I need to be able to count the number of days between these two dates to display to users which dates they can book on.

I have calculated the two dates successfully but I am struggling finding a way to subtract them and return the difference in days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$first; // first datetime object 
$second; // second datetime object 

$diff = $first->diff($second);

echo $diff->days;
```

Also take a look at DateInterval class at php.net

Comment: @Shef - no, I mean what I wrote :)

`days
Total number of days the interval spans. If this is unknown, days will be FALSE.`

Comment: @Shef - "Call to a member function on a non-object". But let's stop the nitpicking here - Gary apparently checked the docs and was able to use the example, modify it and put it to use. It's not hard to check the documentation and see exactly what `format` with `%d` modifier does or what member `days` contains, so if you could, add what's wrong with the example and I'll gladly improve it because I see nothing wrong.

Comment: By running that code, this is the output for me `With $diff->days: 6015
With $diff->format("%d"): 14`.

Comment: Is it mean first date - second date OR second date - first date?

Answer (score 0):

another way is:

```
$datetime1; //first date
$datetime2; //second date

$dayDiff = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

echo $days;
```

Comment: Is it mean first date - second date OR second date - first date?